# UIWebView that load html via "loadHtmlString: baseUrl:" back and forward button feature Via NSArray?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have implemented UIWebView that loads html content in it via UIWebView's

> loadHtmlString: baseUrl:

method , now the

> goBack and goForward

buttons dont work, I need to implement this (back and forward) feature? Any ideas how i can do it ?

Comment: Please check this :- https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=webbrowser

Comment: @Impossible i already checked these links, they are opening links in these browsers. UIWebView automatically manages back and front feature s. But here in my case i have to load html in UIWebView, I need to manage it manually.

Comment: loadHtmlString method only loads some content in UIWebView. In this case there's no transitions between pages, so there's no navigation and no "forwars" or "back" directions.

Comment: @SergeyNikitin i know that Sergey, I just need to implement it manually. by just maintaining history in Nsarray